# How to find contents of Windows updates that were applied?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have an application that depends on the .NET 5 runtime being on the server.  One day it started failing with strange messages.  Turns out the .NET runtime was no longer there.  Ok, thats strange.  So I started looking through windows updates etc. Not sure where to look.

What Ive done so far is look through the Windows app log with the filter on MSIInstaller and I found a few hits on or before the problems started.  Given a specific KB# how can one find the contents of what was being done for this update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the KB number you can search for it in the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx)

Once the update found you can click on the link in the column "title" [image]

This will open a pop up window which will provide a link to the Microsoft support site page for this update.
[image]

This page normally contains all the information you are looking for, including a "File information" section that list all files modified by the update with their version number.

Note that normally a simple google search with the KB number should find this page, but the above method provide more guarantee.